# Flagged post without flagging

Tags: support, stackexchange, closed-questions, flagging

This question has been closed by votes: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/39158/18427

[image: flagged without flagging]

I was the last close vote on this question.  Does that automatically flag this post when there are no comments?

Will it count against me if the flag is disputed or declined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was the last close vote on this question. Does that automatically flag this post when there are no comments?

Yes, if a post is closed with no comments (deleted ones count as none), Community ♦ will raise this autoflag, but only while the site is in beta (it then gets disabled for good).  This happens in any such situation, even when a ♦ moderator closes a question right away without commenting on it first.

> Will it count against me if the flag is disputed or declined?

No, it will not count against you.  Again, this flag is raised by Community ♦, regardless of whom did the closing.  This flag is tied to Community ♦, *not* any user.  As such, it won't appear on your profile.

It may also be worth noting that this particular autoflag isn't too important, and I don't believe that SE even utilizes data coming from their handline.  It *may* help inform a flag reviewer (<s>users with moderator tools or</s> ♦ moderators) that a post was closed without comments, but it is otherwise useless.  It doesn't make a difference whether it's deemed helpful or rejected by a ♦ moderator.  <s>Users with moderator tools can still raise an additional flag (such as an 'invalid' flag) on it for a ♦ moderator if necessary, but it will always be cleared as disputed.</s>  Disputed flags don't count against you.